# Can I use the same iTunes account on all my devices?

Tags: itunes, ipad, accounts, authorization

I've heard a lot of conflicting information about how many devices/computers can share an iTunes account.  What are the actual limits, and are devices distinguished from computers?

My current configuration is (all using the same iTunes account):

- One Windows computer with iTunes
- One iPad
- One iPhone
- One Apple TV

I want to add:

- Another, separate Windows account (on the same computer), that will use a separate install of iTunes
- Two more iPhones
- Another iPad

I'd like everything to share the same iTunes account - is this possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is what the [official Apple documentation](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht4627) says:

> Your Apple ID can have up to **10 devices and computers (combined)**
> associated with it. Each computer must also be authorized using the
> same Apple ID. Once a device or computer is associated with your Apple
> ID, you cannot associate that device or computer with another Apple ID
> for 90 days. You can view which devices or computers are currently
> associated, remove unused devices or computers, and see how long
> before they can be associated with a different Apple ID from the
> Account Information page in iTunes on your computer.
>
> Last Modified: November 14, 2011

Answer (score 3):

Yes. You can set up the same itunes account for all devices

Answer (score 3):

There is a limit of 10 devices. And I can confirm everything is working well with 10 devices! (2 iPhones, 3 iPads, 2 PC, 2 Macs and 1 AppleTV)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can. And if you have iTunes Match you have your Music on all these Devices. I love it.