# Can I copy an app from an iPad to an iPad2?

Tags: ipad, applications

I bought an iPad and bought several apps, then I bought an iPad 2.

Can I copy the apps I bought to the iPad 2 and keep them on my iPad or do I have to buy them again?

Comment: this questions is related to http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/35716/can-i-use-the-same-itunes-account-on-all-my-devices/35729#35729

Answer (score 14):

This is what the [official Apple documentation](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht4627) says:

> Your Apple ID can have up to **10 devices and computers (combined)**
> associated with it. Each computer must also be authorized using the
> same Apple ID. Once a device or computer is associated with your Apple
> ID, you cannot associate that device or computer with another Apple ID
> for 90 days. You can view which devices or computers are currently
> associated, remove unused devices or computers, and see how long
> before they can be associated with a different Apple ID from the
> Account Information page in iTunes on your computer.
>
> Last Modified: November 14, 2011

Answer (score 10):

As long as you use the same account (the same Apple ID) on both your iPad, you can download and use the apps on both.

Comment: Can I backup my ipad and setup my ipad2 with restore from backup to transfer my apps?

Comment: Yes. That way you'll also have the preferences saved.

Comment: You don't have to backup and restore.  Once your iPad2 has the same account, simply open the App Store and download the apps you want; you won't be recharged.  We do this all the time in my family.